# Can't get upload dialog to work

Tags: android, html, forms, browser, upload

So, I'm building a pretty basic website, and I have this:

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post">
<input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

I've done this about a million times before, just works(tm), but trying it on my Android phone, I hit a brick wall, clicking the file input does not yield any file selection dialog?! This kind of dialog has worked all the time I can remember, on any browser I've encountered..
What am I doing wrong here ?

Clicking the input gives me this from logcat:

I/chromium( 5282): [INFO:aw_web_contents_delegate.cc(218)] File Chooser result: mode = 0, file paths =

Answer (score 0):

I dont know about android-uploads but I use:  `<form enctype="multipart/form-data"`   for upload-forms.

Comment: I had that at first, but thought it might be the problem for android, so I tried removing it in my example here, I also tried without accept="image/*" but that does not work.. I downloaded firefox on my Android phone, works fine there.. Can anyone confirm that file-uploads are working correctly in the kitkat browser ?